# Inserting a field (Fields.add) in a bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

Troubling with a Word macro for some while now. I want to insert a field into a specific bookmark - but it fails. Here's the code:

```
.Bookmarks ("text").Range _
                .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
                "LINK  Word.Document.12 ""\\<link>"" \r " _
                , PreserveFormatting:=True
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it looks as if you might be replacing the bookmark "text", in fact your code will add the field into the current selection. You need something more like the following:

```
.Bookmarks("text").Range.Fields.Add _
  Range:=.Bookmarks("text").Range, _
  Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
  Text:="LINK  Word.Document.12 ""\\<link>"" \r ", _
  PreserveFormatting:=True
```

There could be other problems, in which case it may be helpful if you can post the error details or describe what is actually happening when you run your code.

Comment consolidation:

The OP commented that they received the error "Requested Member of the Collection Does Not Exist."

That would occur if there was no bookmark called "text"

Comment: Thanks! But I get this error: Requested Member of the Collection Does Not Exist. Please note I'm new to word macro, so my level is probably pretty bad.

Comment: Holy Smokes! The bookmark were changed in the document! Thank you very much. Beers on me!